# Plot several lines (looping through line styles in cell array) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have written this loop to plot each line of results and I get the error message

> Error using plot. Invalid first data argument.

So far it looks like this

```
test=rand(5,6);
xint=[1:1:6];
LineSpec = {'-y', '--m', ':c', '-r.', '-b', ':s'};

for ii=1:5,
    plot(xint,test(ii,:),LineSpec(ii),'linewidth',2);
    hold on;
    legend_str{ii} = num2str(ii);
end
```

If I use `plot(xint,test(ii,:),'-y','linewidth',2)` then it works. But how can I avoid the error when looping through line styles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my plot is not working in loop for different graph representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151168/why-my-plot-is-not-working-in-loop-for-different-graph-representations)

Comment: @Wolfie, I think you are wrong here. This question is older so it can't be a duplicate of a newer question...

Comment: From meta: *"If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one."*  [link to post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha). The other question has an accepted and upvoted answer, so future users know that answer worked?

Comment: @Wolfie The fact that this question had no upvotes is mainly because the OP did not visit the site since posting it.

Comment: @EBH Agreed, I have now upvoted your answer and marked the other question as duplicate of this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
plot(xint,test(ii,:),...
        LineSpec{ii},...
        'linewidth',2);
```

`LineSpec` is a cell array, so `LineSpec(ii)` returns a cell, while `plot` asks for a character array as line properties.

you can see the difference when you call `LineSpec`:

```
>> LineSpec{1}
ans =
-y
>> LineSpec(1)
ans = 
    '-y'
```

When the output is a cell then the answer is indented and has the single-quote marks.