# Why my plot is not working in loop for different graph representations?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix 'capacity' and I want to plot its row and for that I have used a loop, my code is

```
for j_1=1:8    
plotStyle = {'k -','r +','g *','b.','y o','r--','b d','g s'};   
hold on;
plot(x_1,capacity(j_1,:),plotStyle(j_1));
end
hold off;
```

x_1 is just the x axis, the number of elements in x_1 is equal to the number of columns of capacity.But I am getting error as:

**Error using plot**

**Invalid first data argument**

**Error in varyingDiffusioncofficient (line 124)**

**plot(x_1,capacity(j_1,:),plotStyle)**

Comment: its quite difficult to search in google and get the same question, out of thousands'with different title' though i have tried all combinations I know :). Further this is not exactly the same. I hope you can understand the difficulty involved.

Comment: Flagging as duplicate is routine on stackoverflow, it helps future users find similar questions and avoids answerers wasting their time. EBH answered that question yesterday so knew it existed, as long as you tried searching first it's okay

Comment: And still, what you should do, when you find it is a duplicate (and it's an exact duplicate) is to remove your question, and if needed, ask for clarifications on the existing question.

Comment: You want me to delete the question?

Comment: @Ankit I think it's better to discuss the same issue in the same place, and not to open several identical threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: all you need to do is replace the round braces by curly braces in the call to plot, i.e.

```
plot(x_1,capacity(j_1,:),plotStyle{j_1});
```

Alternatively, you could separate the color and linestyle and make the call this way. This might be convenient when you make even larger plots and want to loop in different ways through the combinations of colors and linestyles.

```
capacity = rand(8,8);     % test data for a workable example
x_1 = 1:8;

for j_1=1:8    
linestyle = {'-','+','*','.','o','--','d','s'};   
color = {'k','r','g','b','y','r','b','g'};   
hold on;
plot(x_1,capacity(j_1,:),'color',color{j_1},'linestyle',linestyle{j_1});
end
hold off;
```

Comment: Just one issue +, d and several others are marker and not linestyle, so this will give error!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is accessing a cell array with normal parentheses `()`, you should be using curly braces `{}`.

```
plotStyle = {'k -','r +','g *','b.','y o','r--','b d','g s'};  
% plotStyle(1) = {'k -'}   : cell
% plotStyle{1} = 'k -'     : string
```

So

```
hold on;  % Move the hold and style assignment outside the loop for efficiency
plotStyle = {'k -','r +','g *','b.','y o','r--','b d','g s'};
for j_1=1:8        
    plot(x_1,capacity(j_1,:),plotStyle{j_1});
end
hold off;
```

[Documentation link for accessing data in a cell array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#zmw57dd0e30216)